# Autoincrement years in RadCombobox VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radcombobox

My issue is adding to RadCombobox years:
The first Year in the RadCombobox starts from 1955 and it incerments by 1 till the current year.
Means Combobox value will hold the value like:
1955,1956,1957,,,,,,2014
Next year it will incermented by 1 automatically.
How can I do it???

```
telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbYear" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select Year"  Enabled="True" Width="172px" AutoPostBack="false"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

ASPX.VB

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    For i As Integer = 1955 To DateTime.Now.Year
        RadComboBox1.Items.Add(New RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))
    Next
End Sub
```

Let me know if any concern.